# Filling first entries of zeros numpy array with entries of a second array

Tags: numpy

In `numpy`, if I have a vector of zeros like this

```
vec1 = np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

and another one like this `vec2 = np.array([1.,2.,3.])`, which is the quickest way to obtain

```
vec3 = np.array([1., 2., 3., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

(Basicaly I want the original vector whose initial entries are filled with the ones of the second vector).

Comment: `vec1[:len(vec2)] = vec2`

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you want to create a new array or modify in place.

New `vec3` array (without altering `vec1` and `vec2`):

```
vec3 = np.concatenate([vec2, vec1[vec2.shape[0]:]])
```

or

```
vec3 = np.r_[vec2, vec1[vec2.shape[0]:]]
```

Modifying `vec1` in place:

```
vec1[:vec2.shape[0]] = vec2
```

used input:

```
vec1 = np.array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
vec2 = np.array([1.,2.,3.])
```